# How do I publish symlinks as regular files over SMB3?

Tags: smb, file-sharing, symlink, domain

I have this file that's dropped in a Mac via rsync, then Windows fetches it but it needs it to be named differently according to use, so the obvious answer, I thought, was to symlink it into all of these files, except that Windows recognizes it's a symlink and can't follow its location.

How do I modify Samba (I'm guessing) to serve it as independent files? i.e; hide the fact that it's a symlink from Windows…or other clients, since I suppose I can't single out a single client.

*If it's relevant to anything; the Mac is domain-joined as are the Windows hosts; domain credentials are being used to set/access share permissions.*

Comment: I tagged this as a dupe because the symptoms and issues are the same - differences in how macOS and Windows handles SMB shares.  It's not a SAMBA thing at all.

Comment: Thanks. That was helpful but how does Synology do it then?? I actually have a Synology unit where I often SSH in and symlink things, even one of the top-level shares [/music] is itself a symlink [of /media/music because Audio Station defaults to that] and it's "correctly fooling" Windows bot for that share in lower in the file system. Is it like a proprietary Synology thing?? This is why I though it was Samba-related, BTW, my bad. :)

Comment: Remember, SMB is a windows thing and SAMBA is SMB (server) implementation on *nix.

Comment: Also a symlink is a link to another file/directory.  When you say "I have a symlink to /media" that really doesn't matter.  SAMBA has to publish the shares it knows about.  So, you can put a symlink as a share in Samba but the clients (macOS/Windows/etc) will still have to access them as I described in the dupe